# Write some text before music staves in lilypond, like instrument names

Tags: lilypond

Is it possible to write some text like "Here is an example of a diatonic whole step" and enter the notes just for a measure length and then keep writing some text after that, I've been reading lilypond manual all day but I couldn't get the code that I need. Sorry if this question is already asked, but I

Answer (score 3):

If there will be more words than music, I would recommend only using Lilypond to produce the music parts and writing the text in other software.

You can write in LaTeX or other software and include the Lilypond score as a graphic. You can use `pdfcrop` or another script to crop the lilypond score image. With LaTeX, you can do this with `\includegraphics` from the `graphicx` package.

Or, you can use `lilypond-book`, which automates this process for you.

Answer (score 3):

```
\version "2.18.2"
\layout {
 \context {
  \Staff 
   \override TimeSignature.stencil = ##f
   \override Clef.stencil = ##f
   \override BarLine.stencil = ##f
 }
}
\markup {

 "Here are three notes"

 \score { \new Staff { b'4 c'' d'' } \layout { indent = #0 } }

 \override #'( line-width . 25 )
 \override #'( baseline-skip . 1.5 )
 \override #'( word-space . 0.5 )
 \override #'( font-size . -3.5 )

 \wordwrap {
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
  aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
  ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
 }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In addition to musarithmia's (very good) answer would just be to provide a `^\markup { Here is an example of a diatonic whole step }` with a given pitch. The text will be above the pitches instead of before the staff, but this way the whole document will be much more uniform throughout.